# Chrome dev tools: auto-completion in console won't work.[press tab won't work]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It's the weirdest thing I encounter.

type `win` in console, console would show `window` and `dow` in gray color as expected.

At this point, press `tab` are expected move the cursor to the end like `window|` and the word `window` are auto completed.

but the word blinked and stay the same.

Ubuntu chrome stable 35.0.1916.153

and this problem stays with my chrome for a few month.[updates are applied normally]

Comment: Please update your Chrome to at least 37. Yours is way out of date and may contain known security flaws.

Comment: I checked it again. My chrome auto updated, and this bug no longer exists.